# Rails rspec - trying to test if an HTTP delete changes a boolean field from false to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to Ruby on Rails.

I have a Project controller with a method that flags a project in the database to be deleted at a later date. The code is as follows:

```
def destroy
  @project.update(:flag_for_deletion => true);

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to projects_path,
                  :notice => 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
  end
end
```

I have a corresponding rspec test:

```
describe "DELETE destroy" do
  it "flags the requested project for deletion" do
    project = Project.create! valid_attributes
    expect {
      delete :destroy, {:id => project.to_param}, valid_session
    }.to change(project, :flag_for_deletion).from(false).to(true)
  end
end
```

I receive the following upon running bundle exec rspec:

```
1) ProjectsController DELETE destroy flags the requested project for deletion

Failure/Error:
   expect {
     delete :destroy, {:id => project.to_param}, valid_session
   }.to change(project, :flag_for_deletion).from(false).to(true)

   expected #flag_for_deletion to have changed from false to true, but did not change
 # ./spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb:141:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The corresponding ruby/rails generated Project model is:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Can anyone provide any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

(Please note, this is my first Stackoverflow question post, so please be patient with any mistakes)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance of `project` in your controller, which is being updated, is a different instance than the one in your tests. The one in the test doesn't change by what happens within the controller. A minimal change to get this working would be change the expectation to something along the lines of

```
change { project.reload.flag_for_deletion }.from(false).to(true)
```

This will just reload all the data from the database before and after invoking the block from `expect`.